# Firefox absolute position preventing button click

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I've read a number of things about this issue, but they don't seem to resolve my issue. Basically, on Firefox the child element (an svg) is overlaying the button and preventing it from being clickable. This code works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I have tried to apply `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, the suggested fix this issue, but the clickable area begins halfway within the element (see image).

[image: clickable area begin half way within the element]

How can I correct this in a way that works across modern browsers?

I just want the button to be the size the child elements. The complication comes from the button needing to be vertically centred in the container div, which is why it has `top: 50%`. This is a reuseable component, so I need a way for it to be vertically centred in a dynamic fashion, so can't just hack the position.

I have mocked up an example here:

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
 alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -43px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  <div>
    <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
  </div>
  
</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add z-index for that particular div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue is not the absolute position of your button, the issue is the absolute position of the div inside the button. the button loses the width and height of the div inside it and is like an empty button (width and height = 0).

remove the absolute position of your div an add the `-43px` to the `top` of your button using calc.

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
 alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 43px);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  <div>
    <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
  </div>
  
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have given `position:absolute` to all div its taking top position of window so the event is not firing. I also calculated vertical alignment, see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e0c5hm13/7/).

HTML:

```
<button>
  <div>
    <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
  </div>

</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 55px);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
    alert('clicked');
});
```